# How Passing indexPath.row between views?

Tags: objective-c, send

I have table view, and I want to send the indexPath.row(index of selected row) to another view.

### ProfesorViewController.m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SCProfesoresCellTableViewCell *cell = (SCProfesoresCellTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

rowselected = indexPath.row;

}
```

### ProfesorViewController.h

```
@interface ProfesorViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property long rowselected;

@end
```

I want to receive value of `rowselected` variable:

### ProfesorDetailViewController.m

```
@synthesize rowselected;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSLog(@"BANDERA DE LA FILA %ld", rowselected);
}
```

### ProfesorDetailViewController.h

```
@interface ProfesorDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property long rowselected;
@end
```

But the value of `rowselected` is always 0. 
I don't know how to send the value of variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have two classes with properties with the same name, but you never assign the value of one to the value of the other. At some point you need to take your instance of `ProfesorDetailViewController` and set `rowselected` on it, likely when initializing it.

```
ProfesorDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[ProfesorDetailViewController alloc] init];
detailViewController.rowselected = self.rowselected;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand where to pass data between `ProfesorViewController` and `ProfesorDetailViewController` so pass data between to view controller

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ProfesorDetailViewController *profesor=[[ProfesorDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ProfesorDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    rowselected=indexPath.row;
    search.Selected=_selected;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profesor animated:YES];
}
```

Now you get the value of selected row index in `ProfesorDetailViewController` viewController properly..